# html5 canvas rotate accepting invalid radians

Tags: canvas, rotation

I have no problem rotating a canvas. My question is that in the examples I have seen, and I've verified it, if I use an ever-increasing angle and hence an ever-increasing radian after conversion (angle * Math.PI/180), the rotate still works.

Should I just assume that if the radian is too large that some sort of modulo is used to toss out the extra spins?

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rotate 364 degrees, it is the exact same as rotating 4 degrees, etc etc.

The fact canvas uses radians instead of degrees doesn't change that. You can rotate any number of radians, and it will just "circle back around" after every 2pi.